# Get stdClass Object value

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I'm trying to get a value from `stdClass` Object array with no success.

Here is the code I'm running:

```
 $myjson =
 '{"2":{"label":"","value":"","type":null,"validation":null,"required":null},
 "6":{"label":"files","value":"getThisValue","type":"file0","validation":null,"required":null},
 "3":{"label":"location","value":"val3","type":"hidden","validation":"","required":"0"}
 ,"0":{"custom3":"zz","value":"","label":""},"1":{"custom3":"zz","value":"","label":""}
 }';

$json = json_decode($myjson);

echo $json[6]->'value';
```

This is doesn't work, If I `Print_r` the JSON after decoding `(print_r($json))`, the array will look like this:

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( [label] => [value] =>
[type] => [validation] => [required] => ) 
    [6] => stdClass Object (
[label] => files [value] => getThisValue [type] => file0 [validation]
=> [required] => ) 
    [3] => stdClass Object ( [label] => location [value] => val3 [type] => hidden [validation] => [required] => 0 ) 
    [0]
=> stdClass Object ( [custom3] => zz [value] => [label] => ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [custom3] => zz [value] => [label] => ) )
```

I need the Value: `getThisValue`. Any idea how I can get it? (I tried many options with no success).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `echo $json["6"]["value"];`
But for this you have to use `json_decode($myjson, true);` true, to get an array.

Because it's going to be two arrays inside each other and not an object you have to use 2 brackets.

Comment: Thanks.. thats the answer ;)

Comment: No Problem my friend.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `true` to your `json_decode`, like this: `json_decode($myjson, true);`, it will now convert your json object to an associative array.

And from there on you can get to the value you want by requesting the key, just like other arrays.

```
$newArray = json_decode($myjson, true);
echo $newArray['something'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a std object as an array. But in order to get your code working just add this line:

```
$json = get_object_vars($json);
```

After this you can access it like this:

```
echo $json[6]->value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values from stdObject without converting it to array, you can do it like this:

```
echo $json->{'6'}->value
```

You can use the `{'property_name'}` notation to get a value of a class property with non-standard name (for ex. a number).